# Typescript: Convert union of similar objects to object type

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to transform union of similar objects to object type using TypeScript typings?

#### Input

```js
type I = {
  key: 'foo',
  value: Foo,
} | {
  key: 'bar',
  value: Bar,
};
```

#### Output

```js
type O = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
};
```

I am not sure it is possible. But who knows?
Note that the task is not a duplicate to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type).

Comment: That's not an intersection.

Comment: It's not clear what the algorithm would even be to get from your "input" to your "output" unless you had a type that happened to be a union of a bunch of types with key properties of type string and value properties of various types.

And how would you use this output? You want an expression that produces `O` from `I`? How does that help you? `O` is not that hard to type into your code -- you did it above.

So yeah, see whether you can improve or clarify the question, I'd say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TypeScript 4.1 this is a straightforward [mapped type with key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types). You can iterate over each member `T` of the `I` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) (it's a union, not an intersection) and [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the key/value types: `T['key']` for the key and `T['value']` for the value.  Like this:

```
type O = { [T in I as T['key']]: T['value'] };
/* type O = {
    foo: Foo;
    bar: Bar;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrqJLIigEJxQ77IBGJcpRC0GuXGACeABxQBJZAF4eBANYRJJAOQxMWgDS8AbnAA2AVwgkM6Q-WQAfFcnWbkWvlwPGzlkpyg7OgkZFAB5JRxkAG0AFWRQZAU4UmRY6K1XLQBdbJJ0rRMLCBzkejoAegAqZClZZAjlPAICXXRrTDoW-i5-Ljp7KorcIA)